# how to change relativeLayout background color from inside a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a button `btnSwitch` and I want to make the flash light blink and the background color to change continuously as long as I'm holding the button and to stop doing that when I release my finger the colors for the background are white and black the flash is working right but the background changes one time only the black and never returns to white.

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public Button btnSwitch;

      btnSwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private Handler handler;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v,  MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()){

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (handler != null) return true;
                        handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(thread, 14);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                       if (handler == null) return true;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(thread);
                        handler = null;
                        break;
            }
                return false;
            }
           Runnable thread= new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            this.wait(7);
                            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            turnonflash();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            this.wait(7);
                            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            turnofflash();

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 14);
                    }}
           };
        });
    }
```

and this is the XML FILE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/backv">

<Button

    android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"

    android:text="switch"

    android:contentDescription="@null"
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);`on the UiThread:

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
          public void run() {
              relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Same probleme on the second runonUIThraed the background becomes black then the first runonUIThread never runs again

Comment: It's just an idea - but try setting 7 to 1000 for testing - maybe your code works but 7ms is too short for the human eye to recognize the color changes?